# Return lists updated by for loop in a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class StoreVal which has two functions update() and get_value(), update() function monitors ftp and calls another function called extract() on each new file as it appears in the ftp and it extracts two values from each new file on in ftp directory.
These values are added to the two lists declared in the class by by list.extend method.

I am trying to print the lists as they are updated by the get_value() function, but nothing seems to happen. My Code (simplified to show concept):

```
list_1 = [[225,656,898,78], [565,887,56,36], [56,23,47,89,78], [25,36,96,47]]


def extract(list_obj):
    sp=[]
    corr=[]
    for x in list_obj:
        sp.append(x[0])
        corr.append(x[1])
    return sp , corr

#x ,y = extract(list_1)

class StoreCorr:

    x= []
    y=[]

    def update(self):
        while True:
            sp , corr = extract(list_1)

            self.x.extend(sp)
            self.y.extend(corr)


    def get_values(self):
        self.update()
        return self.x, self.y




store = StoreCorr()

r, t = store.get_values()


print(r, t )
```

This is a simplified version , the program runs but nothing happens.

The the list object is a new file as it will appear on FTP which I am monitoring with a while loop.

I want to print x=[], y=[] as they are extended by the while loop by new list_obj being fed to the extract function.

Comment: Think about what will cause the `while True` loop in `update` to exit. Will it ever exit?

Comment: I was thinking about the same when dealing with files , but I am not able to get my head around on how to watch the FTP directory with an endless while loop and return the values from it at the same time. Which are extracted from each new file.

Comment: If you want a loop to run in the background while the rest of the code executes, you'll need to look into Threads and related concepts. Returning data from an asynchronous process (code running in the background) is a difficult task though. I'm not sure how rehearsed you are with Python, but you might want to tackle something easier before moving onto that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for hinting at the solution , this is what I want to do exactly , run the loop which watches the ftp in background and  return data from that , which will be used by rest of the code. -Thanks

Comment: Ya. The simple solution would be to start a thread that runs `update` in the background. How exactly you'll get data out of the background loop though depends on how it's being used/consumed. Passing a list to the thread and appending to it as data is available may be sufficient though. Then you just need to periodically check the list.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `while True:` line.  The reason is that the while never breaks so your program never exits.

```
list_1 = [[225,656,898,78], [565,887,56,36], [56,23,47,89,78], [25,36,96,47]]


def extract(list_obj):
    sp=[]
    corr=[]
    for x in list_obj:
        sp.append(x[0])
        corr.append(x[1])
    return sp , corr

#x ,y = extract(list_1)

class StoreCorr:

    x= []
    y=[]

    def update(self):
        sp , corr = extract(list_1)
        self.x.extend(sp)
        self.y.extend(corr)


    def get_values(self):
        self.update()
        return self.x, self.y




store = StoreCorr()

r, t = store.get_values()


print(r, t )*
```